# Subsribe and publish conversion problem

Tags: ros, ros-control, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to write an own Subscribe and Publisk node. I would like ti subscribe to the joystick and publish to my motors. For the publish i create with a launchfile to topics, I use the JointVelocityController for that, so they are from type std_msgs:.Float 64. And I think the type i get from the joy is Float32. So when ich start building the node i get this error:

```
/home/ae/catkin_ws/src/epos_hardware-indigo-devel/epos_hardware/src/nodes/talker.cpp:30:17: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std_msgs::Float64’ and ‘float’)
   velocity_left = 1000*joy->axes[7];
                 ^
/home/ae/catkin_ws/src/epos_hardware-indigo-devel/epos_hardware/src/nodes/talker.cpp:30:17: note: candidate is:
In file included from /home/ae/catkin_ws/src/epos_hardware-indigo-devel/epos_hardware/src/nodes/talker.cpp:2:0:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note: std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >& std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&)
 struct Float64_
        ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/std_msgs/Float64.h:22:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘float’ to ‘const std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> >&’
make[2]: *** [epos_hardware-indigo-devel/epos_hardware/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/src/nodes/talker.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [epos_hardware-indigo-devel/epos_hardware/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

This is my Subscribe and Publish node:

```
  #include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float64.h"
#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>

#define MAX_VELO 80000

class SubscribeAndPublish
{
     
    public:
    SubscribeAndPublish()
    
    {
    
    
  
        sub_joint= n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("joy",1, &SubscribeAndPublish::joyCallback, this);
    
        pub_velocity_left= n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("left_velocity_controller/command", 1);
        pub_velocity_right= n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("right_velocity_controller/command", 1);
        
        
    }
    
  void joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy)
    {
        std_msgs::Float64 velocity_left;
    
        // do something with the code
        velocity_left = 1000*joy->axes[7];
        pub_velocity_right.publish(velocity_left);
        pub_velocity_left.publish(velocity_left);
    }
    
    private:
    
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher pub_velocity_right;
    ros::Publisher pub_velocity_left;
    ros::Subscriber sub_joint;
};
    


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"subsribe_and_publish");

    SubscribeAndPublish SAPObject;
    
    ros::spin();
    
    return 0;
    
 }
```

I think the problem is that i have different kind of types, but i don't now how i can converted them or what i can do.

Thanks for your ideas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247027/subsribe-and-publish-conversion-problem/) by [Milliau](https://answers.ros.org/users/27715/milliau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try changing from `velocity_left = 1000*joy->axes[7];` to `velocity_left.data = 1000*joy->axes[7];`. In the [std_msgs/Float64](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float64.html) the field holding the float is `data`. What the error is saying is that currently you are trying to assign the entire message (not just a single message field) to a float value.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Milliau](https://answers.ros.org/users/27715/milliau/) on 2016-11-02**:
Thanks this solve the problem :-)